# Part of the third Isomorphism theorem for modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

On Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_C_(modules), the second part of the third isomorphism theorem for modules says the following.

Let $M$ be an $R$ module and let $T$ be a submodule of $M$.
Then every submodule of $\frac{M}{T}$ is of the form $\frac{S}{T}$ for some submodule $S$ of $M$, such that $ T \subseteq S \subseteq M$.

Initially, I attempted as follows;

Let $I$ be a submodule of $\frac{M}{T}$. Define $\phi : I \rightarrow M$ by  $\phi( m + T ) = m, m \in I $. Then I tried to use $\phi$ to show $T \subseteq Im(\phi) \subseteq M$ and $I = \frac{Im(\phi)}{T}$. However I then realised that $\phi$ is not well defined,  since if $m_1 + T = m_2 + T$, both are in $I$, and $m_1 \neq m_2$, $\phi$ maps them to different elements even though they are the same element in the domain.

Does anyone have a hint/proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let $\pi \colon M \to M/T$ be the canonical quotient map, and consider $S := \pi^{-1}(I)$. Note that, as $\pi$ is surjective, $(S/I=)\pi(S)=\pi(\pi^{-1}(I)) = I$, and obviously $T \subseteq S$ because $0+T \in I \implies \pi^{-1}(\{0+T\}) \subseteq \pi^{-1}(I)$.

Comment: One way to do this is to actually pin down what $S$ must be: what if you set $S := \{ m \in M : m + T \in I \}$ for $I \subset M + T$ a submodule, and then show that $S$ is a submodule of $M$?

Comment: Is it the second part of the third theorem or the third part of the second theorem?

Comment: @markvs It is the second part of the third theorem, which is also called theorem C on the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @turnip_man: Abstract algebra Wikipedia pages as well as Linear Algebra Wikipedia pages are not as valuable source of information as other Wikipedia math pages, unfortunately. A good Abstract Algebra book would be a better source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments, If $I$ is a submodule of $\frac{M}{T}$, the submodule  of M given by $S = \{ m \in M : m + T \in I \} $ gives $ T \subseteq S \subseteq M$ and $I = \frac{S}{T} $.